# pinterest sorcery

Tags: javascript

maybe it's some kind of default behavior that I'm ignoring,
but at the moment I haven't the slightest idea of how once you click an element on the homepage of http://pinterest.com the url actually changes ie: http://pinterest.com/pin/60165344991931565/

At the same time the page is not changed!
It just loads ajax content and injects the result inside the html.

I never saw a behavior such as this. I'm using latest Chrome.

Comment: and your question is? $10 says they're using a javascript app framework like [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three words : History API HTML5

And one link : http://html5demos.com/history

Answer (score 1):

There is a project on github for this: http://pjax.heroku.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out history.pushState, history.replaceState and popstate.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API for older browser.
For example, there is integrated this library: http://spb-piksel.ru/history/ a copy of the site http://html5demos.com/history but with the integration of the library. Check on older browsers too.